# Navigation between Files when Pages is out of src folder with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth and NextJS. My directory structure is in the picture below. I want to navigate to Hello.tsx in the components folder using "Link" but setting href to '/components/Hello' does not work after adding a pages directory outside of source (Required to do in NextAuth). Does anyone know how to do this?

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHnSf.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Hello component to be a page component that you can display with  an URL then you have to move it to the page folder. It will be automatically called when you navigate to `/hello`

Comment: I tried doing this, but it messes up a lot of stuff in my app. For example, tailwind is not imported anymore after moving the file over and for some reason my searchParams gets messed up. Is this the only solution?

Comment: I was able to fix a lot of stuff. But how do I import tailwind for this component when it is moved out of apps?

Comment: @nsyh sorry I have no idea about tailwind 